# How do I allow custom input in a LWC combo box (or something similar)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

Salesforce offers the `lightning-combobox` for showing a field with a list of predefined options. When I think of "combobox," I think of a UI widget that offers predefined options but also allows the input of custom content. For example, this is something I quickly put together in another platform. The menu offers three options, but I can input something not available in the menu as well.

[image]

How can I do this with LWC?

Answer (score 1):

The SLDS guidelines for [Combobox](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/) work as you describe. It provides a list of options, and a way to enter any arbitrary value. Unfortunately, the `lightning-combobox` provided by [`lightning-base-components`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components), which are essentially open-source implementations of what LWC in Salesforce uses, doesn't have that functionality built in. However, as far as I'm aware, [`combobox`](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/combobox) from [`base-components-recipes`](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/) does support arbitrary input. You can also find other open-source implementations to use as a guideline, or possibly even directly for your use case (make sure to read the LICENSE.md file first). For what it's worth, I've implemented part of a Combobox using SLDS directly (just the filtering, typeahead stuff, mostly), and it wasn't terribly bad, perhaps a few hours of work.